# Unexpected value 'HttpClientModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to consume an API and test it on my local machine but apparently there is this error that I can't figure out how to solve. please see below my app.module.ts --

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Pipe, Directive,Component} from '@angular/core';

import {Compiler, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CompilerFactory} from '@angular/core';
import {JitCompilerFactory} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
export function createCompiler(compilerFactory: CompilerFactory) {
  return compilerFactory.createCompiler();
}

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UploadResumeComponent } from './upload-resume/upload-resume.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './reusable-components/header/header.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './reusable-components/banner/banner.component';
import { SideMenuComponent } from './reusable-components/side-menu/side-menu.component';
import { MainBodyComponent } from './main-body/main-body.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './reusable-components/footer/footer.component';
import { DndDirective } from './dnd.directive';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UploadResumeComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    SideMenuComponent,
    MainBodyComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    DndDirective,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS, useValue: {}, multi: true},
    {provide: CompilerFactory, useClass: JitCompilerFactory, deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS]},
    {provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory]},
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

on my console in the browser, this was the error message I kept on getting --

"Unexpected value 'HttpClientModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation"

Any advise with this one? Thanks in advance

Comment: Modules should go into the imports section (yours is in the declarations)

Comment: Awesome, that did the fix! many thanks @AviadP.